# How to show a default image inside a picture tag?

Tags: html

So I'm using the picture tag to show an image depending on the size of the screen... the problem I'm having is when none of the sources load the img should come in and be shown right? But this is no working it's just showing the alt attribute. Is there another way to do this or a way to fix it? Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="invalid.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="invalid.jpg">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9754/mountains-clouds-forest-fog.jpg" alt="test">
</picture>

</body>
</html>
```

This other one is just to show that the above image url is valid:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9754/mountains-clouds-forest-fog.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9754/mountains-clouds-forest-fog.jpg">
  <img src="invalid" alt="test">
</picture>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below way,

```
 <img src="invalid" alt="test" onerror="this.setAttribute('srcset', 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/9754/mountains-clouds-forest-fog.jpg')">
```

another way in js,

```
const picture = document.querySelector("picture");

picture.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
  // Check if the event target is the img tag
  if (event.target.tagName === "IMG") {
    // Load the default image
    event.target.src = "fallback.jpg";
  }
});
```